# When is a cycle in $KK^G(A,A)$ with zero operator the identity cycle?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kk-theory

Given a cycle of the form $(\pi,H,0)$ in $KK^G(A,A)$, when is it equivalent to the identity cycle $1_A=(i_A,A,0)$?

The operator $T=0$, and $\pi:A \rightarrow L(H)$ may be injective.

Any criterions how to decide this?

Comment: I know $l^2(G)$ is a $C_0(G)$-$C_0(G)$ bi-module but how to make it a Hilbert $C_0(G)$-module? What is the inner product?

Comment: I have edited it.